# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS unable to setup second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, amd-graphics, xrandr

Upon fresh installing Ubuntu 22.04 today, I came across a problem that my main monitor that I want to use (ASUS ROG PG278Q 2k 144Hz Display port) is not being detected. Meanwhile my second monitor(Dell 1080p HDMI Port). I use RX 570 and Ubuntu is on a dual boot(both monitors working fine on Win10).

I've searched everything and anything, tried various methods from people that had same problem and everything that worked for them just won't work on my end.

> Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
> XWAYLAND0 connected 640x480+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
> 640x480       59.38*+
> 320x240       59.52
> 640x400       59.20
> 320x200       58.96
> 640x350       59.77
> XWAYLAND2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
> 1920x1080     74.91*+
> 1440x1080     74.92
> 1400x1050     74.87
> 1280x1024     74.90
> 1280x960      74.86
> 1152x864      74.82
> 1024x768      74.67
> 800x600       74.91
> 640x480       74.77
> 320x240       73.82
> 1680x1050     74.89
> 1440x900      74.85
> 1280x800      74.76
> 720x480       74.51
> 640x400       74.23
> 320x200       73.70
> 1600x900      74.89
> 1368x768      74.73
> 1280x720      74.78
> 1024x576      74.80
> 864x486       74.45
> 720x400       74.23
> 640x350       74.53
> 2560x1440 (0x3e6) 241.500MHz -HSync +VSync
> h: width  2560 start 2608 end 2640 total 2720 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
> v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1481           clock  59.95Hz
> 2560x1440_120.00 (0x3f0) 497.750MHz +HSync -VSync
> h: width  2560 start 2608 end 2640 total 2720 skew    0 clock 183.00KHz
> v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1525           clock 120.00Hz

This is what I get upon typing "xrandr"(saw that on similar post). I tried updating all drivers(there are none aditional).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhwP7.png)

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but is the monitor plugged in (all the way)? I've made that mistake... if so, unplug the monitor, plug it in, wait maybe two seconds, and then [edit] the output of `dmesg` into your question. You may need to do `sudo dmesg`

Comment: Just checked. I forgot to add that I have a picture response on it, but its maybe 30x30 cm in size and everything around is black. I can see same background screen on both monitors, I can drag apps across them but it's unusable since it's so small. Here is my dmesg output https://pastebin.com/Stueddyr

Comment: Same with me. External display was working fine in fresh Ubuntu (without AMD drivers) and stopped working after `amdgpu-install` usage. Same for connected to laptop's HDMI slot and to docking station.